# Ember.js: How to refresh parent route templates in a nested route scenario?

Tags: ember.js

My page layout (application template) looks like this (simplified):

[image: Ember page layout]

I use it for different routes (offer list + offer detail, customer list + customer detail). Lists are shown in the sub-navigation outlet.

My router's code:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    //...
    this.resource('offers', function () {
        this.resource('offer', { path: '/:offer_id' });
    });
}
```

My Routes:

```
App.OffersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function () {
       return App.Offer.find();
   },
   renderTemplate: function (controller, model) {
       this.render('offer-list', { 
           into: 'application', outlet: 'sub-navigation', controller: 'offers' });
       this.render('offer-list-title', { into: 'application', outlet: 'page-title' });
       this.render('offer-list-content', { into: 'application' });
   }
});

App.OfferRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function (params) {
      return App.Offer.find(params.offer_id);
   },
   renderTemplate: function () {
      this.render('offer-title', { into: 'application', outlet: 'page-title' });
      this.render('offer-content', { into: 'application' });
   }
});
```

Now this works so far.

```
http://.../#/offers
```

shows the list and the title "Offer summary" and static html content. I click on one of the offers in the list, going to

```
http://.../#/offers/23
```

all okay: it still shows the list of offers in the sub-navigation area and the correct title and the content of the offer.

**Now my problem:**

If I return to the

```
http://.../#/offers
```

page (using a #linkTo helper on a menu), then the {{outlet}} / content area becomes empty (not the static html from before) and the title is still the title in {{page-title}} of the offer/23 route.

How can I let my app "re-render" the template as defined in the OffersRoute `renderTemplate()`?

*P.S.: I'm using Ember.js 1.0.0-RC.3*

Comment: How is the link on your menu being constructed? Do you get the same behavior if you go to the URL referenced by the link directly? I'm guessing that the model is not getting built as expected when trying to render the the route again.

Comment: @LanceHarper 1. The link in the menu is build with a linkTo helper: {{#linkTo "offers"}} All Offers {{/linkTo}} -- 2. Accessing the pages inserting the URL directly in the browser works for all pages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the built-in `Index` routes and maintaining the `ApplicationRoute` -> `OffersRoute` -> `OfferRoute` hierarchy will solve your issue.

If you turn on the router transition logging you will see that when navigating to `Offers` you are actually entering the `Offers.Index` route:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
});
```

This means that you can set your static Offers title and set the static Offers content in `OffersIndexRoute` and it will be correctly set the first time and set again if you link back to it from inside of an offer detail page.  For this to work you also must preserve the `ApplicationRoute` -> `Offers` -> `Offer` `{{outlet}}` hierarchy by not directly rendering everything into the `ApplicationRoute`'s `{{outlet}}`. The reason you must preserve this hierarchy is that by rendering the child (`Offer` template) directly into the `Application` template you remove the `Offers` template and when you try to go back to the `OffersRoute` its template has been removed and it shows nothing.

### Index route

Use `OffersIndexRoute` to fill in the `ApplicationRoute`'s `{{outlet}}` and the `{{outlet page-title}}`.

JS:

```
//this renders the title and the main content for Offers
App.OffersIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function (controller, model) {
    this.render('offer-list-title', { into: 'application', outlet: 'page-title' });
    this.render();
  }
});

App.OffersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function () {
       return App.Offer.find();
   },
   renderTemplate: function (controller, model) {
     this.render('offer-list', { 
         into: 'application', outlet: 'sub-navigation', controller: 'offers' });
     
     // render this in OffersIndexRoute instead
     //this.render('offer-list-title', { into: 'application', outlet: 'page-title' });
     
     this.render('offer-list-content', { into: 'application' });
   }
});
```

Handlebars:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="offer-list-content">
  {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="offers/index">
  Offers content
</script>
```

The outlet in the `offers-list-content` will be filled in by the `OffersIndexRoute` or by the `Offer` template, depending on what the current route is.

### Maintaining `{{outlet}}` hierarchy

Allow the `OfferRoute` to render it's content template into the `OffersRoute` template instead of forcing it into the `ApplicationRoute`.

```
App.OfferRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function (params) {
      return App.Offer.find(params.offer_id);
   },
   renderTemplate: function () {
     this.render('offer-title', { into: 'application', outlet: 'page-title' });
     
     // preserve the hierarchy and render into the Offers {{outlet}}, which is the default
     //this.render('offer-content', { into: 'application' });
     this.render('offer-content');
   }
});
```

[Working JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/iwiqoy/1/edit)

Comment: This works great, thanks! Really this should be front-and-center in the docs, or even a default tutorial. Maybe rendering child views to the main outlet should be the expected behavior, and rendering them to their parent's outlet implemented as a feature...?