# Ember direct URL or page refresh empty model

Tags: url, ember.js, refresh, routes

I have an index page with different courses. From that index page you can navigate to a specific course by a link-to. When I navigate to a course everything works fine but when I refresh the page or go to that URL directly the model is empty.

This is how my code looks like:

```
index.hbs ---------------------------------------
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center">
    <h1>Become a Tjuna Fish</h1>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x300">
    <p>Leer met de technieken werken die bij Tjuna worden gebruikt en ontwikkel    jezelf tot een echte Tjuna Fish!</p>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <h1 class="text-center">Cursussen</h1>
    {{#each}}
        <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        <div class="row">
            <img {{bind-attr src="img"}}/>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          {{#link-to "course" this}}{{title}}{{/link-to}}
        </div>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
    </div>

scripts ---------------------------------------
BecomeTjunaFish.Router.map(function () {
// Add your routes here
 this.resource('index', {path: '/'});
 this.resource('course', { path: ':url'});

});

BecomeTjunaFish.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
 // admittedly, this should be in IndexRoute and not in the
 // top level ApplicationRoute; we're in transition... :-)
 model: function () {
    return this.store.find('course');
 }

});

BecomeTjunaFish.CourseRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
 // admittedly, this should be in IndexRoute and not in the
 // top level ApplicationRoute; we're in transition... :-)
 model: function (params) {
    return this.store.find('course', params.id);
 }

});

BecomeTjunaFish.Course = DS.Model.extend({
 title: DS.attr('string'),
 img: DS.attr('string'),
 goal: DS.attr('string'),
 targetGroup: DS.attr('string'),
 prerequisites: DS.attr('string'),
 url: DS.attr('string')
});

BecomeTjunaFish.Course.FIXTURES = [
 {
  id: 1,
  title: 'Tjuna Basis',
  img: 'http://placehold.it/200x200',
  goal: 'kunnen werken met de basis tools en opmaaktalen die Tjuna gebruikt',
  targetGroup: 'frontend developers in wording',
  prerequisites: 'geen',
  url: 'basis_cursus'
 },
 {
  id: 2,
  title: 'Tjuna Frontend',
  img: 'http://placehold.it/200x200',
  goal: '',
  targetGroup: '',
  prerequisites: '',
  url: 'frontend_cursus'
 },
 {
  id: 3,
  title: 'Tjuna Backend',
  img: 'http://placehold.it/200x200',
  goal: '',
  targetGroup: '',
  prerequisites: '',
  url: 'backend_cursus'
 }
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the dynamic segment as `:id` in your router. What happens is,

1. When you transition via `{{link-to}}`, you pass the entire model object. Hence while retrieving the course model(`this.store.find('course', params.id);`) in `route#model` , you have the `id` with you and thereby fetching the model with no trouble.
2. When you hit back or refresh the course page, all you have is the course `url` in the address bar URL. This course `url` (note the entire course object) will be passed to the course `route#model` hook where you try to retrieve using the `id`. Hence it blows up

So make your dynamic segment as `id` in the router to make it work. You can also fetch the records with name.

[Working Jsbin](http://jsbin.com/wamiho/2)

Comment: Great it works! This is exactly what I was looking for. 

I changed

    this.resource('course', { path: ':url'}); 

to 

    this.resource('course', { path: ':id'});

Do you also know how to make the urls nested and dynamic without nested templates?

Example:

    domain/#/:course/:lesson/:topic 

I looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17012806/idiomatic-emberjs-for-nested-routes-but-non-nested-templates but couldn't figure out how to make it work for my app.

Answer (score 0):

As selvagsz explained, I had to change :url to :id in the router.

I also wanted to have nested URL's without nested templates. Something like this:

```
this.resource('index', {path: '/'});
this.resource('course', { path: ':course_id'}, function(){
  this.resource('lesson', {path: ':lesson_id'}, function(){
    this.resource('topic', {path: ':topic_id'});
  });
});
```

Problem with this is, when I go to course/lesson url the lesson template will only render when I have an outlet in the course template. I want the course template to be replaced with the lesson template but keep the same nested url.

I fixed this by using the renderTemplate function of Ember like this:

```
BecomeTjunaFish.LessonRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function (params) {
   return this.store.find('lesson', params.lesson_id);
  },
  renderTemplate: function() {
  this.render('lesson', { into: 'application'})
  }
});
```

This works great but when I navigate back, for example to course, it is not working anymore. Instead of only have a courseRoute I also needed a courseIndexRoute which uses the same model as courseRoute and place the renderTemplate in the CourseIndexRoute (same for LessonIndexRoute). Example:

```
BecomeTjunaFish.CourseRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
 model: function (params) {
    return this.store.find('course', params.course_id);
 }

});

BecomeTjunaFish.CourseIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
 model: function () {
  return this.modelFor('course');
 },
 renderTemplate: function() {
   this.render('course', { into: 'application'})
 }

});
```

To me it seems to be a lot of code and I don't know if this is the right way to do this. At the moment this is good enough for me, it's working :) But I would appreciate it to have feedback on it and would like to know if there are other / better ways to fix this.

*I used this question as inspiration: [Redirecting from edit to parent resource doesn't (re)render template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16962258/redirecting-from-edit-to-parent-resource-doesnt-rerender-template)