# Ember.js: How to render a child route's view into application and navigate back to parent's route

Tags: jquery, ember.js

The use case is that I have an index listing displayed in {{outlet}} and I want the detail views for each item to display in the same outlet, owned by 'application'.
This is no problem to do with:

```
renderTemplate: (controller, model)->
this.render('show', {
  into: 'application'
});
```

However the problem is that when returning to the index page `{{#linkTo 'index'}}Index{{/linkTo}}` then the index view will no longer render.

The console throws the error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'connectOutlet' of undefined`

Here is a fiddle reproducing the issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/genkilabs/spAbn/3/

What is the correct way to have all my child views display in the application's main outlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is shift the `show` route to be parallel with the `index` route instead of nested.

```
App.Router.map ->
  @resource 'index', path: '/'
  @resource 'show', path: ':person_id'
```

The issue is the `show` route was originally nested inside of the `index` route. The `renderTemplate` call overwrote the original `index` template with the `show` template, but Ember still expected the `index` template to be present in the hierarchy.

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/spAbn/4/)

Comment: Thanks for answering this. I was aiming to maintain the show, and other children views, within the scope of the object type. ie. if I have a menu item "Animals" then I want internal pages for "cats" and "dogs" but I still want the Animals tab to maintain the 'active' class etc. It turns out I found a better solution in one of your other answers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16346204/484689